# react js with redux fetch always return an empty json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, redux

I am trying to request an API without ajax call (why would I import the whole library for simply making an ajax call?).

So I decided to follow the fetch function flow as it is described in the Redux doc (which I migrate with last week).

`import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'`

Thus, I have this short function:

```
export function fetchPosts(value) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestPosts(value))
        return fetch(Config.serverUrl + '/' + value, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: Config.authorizationToken
            },
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(value, json)))
    };
};
```

but when I do a console.log in this next step function:

```
function receivePosts(value, json) {
    console.log(json);
    return {
        type: RECEIVE_POSTS,
        value,
        posts: json.data.children.map(child => child.data)
    };
};
```

I can see that my json is an empty object.

The network return this:

`General:
Request URL:https://shelob-v2.dev.blippar.com/v2/categories
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:52.25.79.166:443`

Header:
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization, Content-Type, X-Pouet-UniqueID, X-Pouet-UniqueRunID
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PATCH, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 27 Apr 2016 14:14:36 GMT`

Am I doing something definitely wrong with it?

Comment: Can you look at the request/response in the network tab (chrome)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redux syntax looks correct, but it looks like the request was an OPTIONS request and not a GET request. Try adding `method: 'GET'` to your fetch options.

```
export function fetchPosts(value) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestPosts(value))
        return fetch(Config.serverUrl + '/' + value, {
            method: 'GET', // here
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: Config.authorizationToken
            },
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(value, json)))
    };
};
```

Comment: Indeed, this time my json is filled !

Do you have any idea why I still have this output error:
```Cannot read property 'children' of undefined``` ? is the treatment on the json of receivePosts deprecated?

Comment: It sounds like this code is incorrect: `json.data.children.map(child => child.data)`. I would use network dev tools or add a `console.log(json)` in your fetchPosts or receivePosts to know exactly what your response looks like and go from there.